# Why did Nils Debruuk insist on reading the manifesto?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-fallout

In [*Mission: Impossible - Fallout*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4912910/), when Team Hunt was trying to get the mobile password from Dr. Debruuk, he wanted the manifesto to be read and broadcasted on air or he won't give those passkeys.

After they read the manifesto, he typed those passwords saying:

> Well, it's not going to help you now.....What's done is done.

**Why is reading the manifesto on air so important to him?**

If he gave those passwords without the manifesto being read on TV, what did he fear wouldn't happen? Was he trying to send any signal to anybody? If any, what was that and to who? What is the relation of "what's done is done" with reading that manifesto?

Comment: I'm sure it's a meme - much exploited since at least James Bond. The evil villain wants to explain the full extent of his evil plan, thus giving the hero time & opportunity to thwart him. [Possibly under, "No, I expect you to die, Mr Bond"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Because he wants people to understand

....and, in his mind, bring about world peace

He says..

> "There has never been peace without first a great suffering. The greater the suffering, the greater the peace.
>
> See, this will unite them. **When they read this manifesto they'll understand.**"

Now, he can post it on the internet but that doesn't *guarantee* that a lot of people will read/hear it.

On the other hand if it's read on TV, *millions* of people will read it and, he hopes, be converted to his way of thinking.

As for...

> Well, it's not going to help you now.....What's done is done.

He doesn't care about John Lark....as far as he knows the weapons have already detonated and his part of his anti-religion plan is complete.